# what's the error in this jquery plugin pattern?

Tags: jquery-plugins

Lately I stumbled upon some jquery sliders and I actually refactored one to a more modern look with success!
So, I decided to explore more the uniqueness of private variables with every instance created for my module. Here an abstract example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Namespaces</title>
<style>
  h1 {
     color: #808080;
  }
  h1:hover {
     color: #000000;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dot {
     border-style: dotted;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Click Me</h1>

<h3>Properties of first module attached here.</h3>
<p id="first"></p>
<h3>Properties of second module attached here (filtered by hasOwnProperty()).</h3>
<p id="second"></p>

<script src="../jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script>
////////////////////////Module Definition////////////////////////
;(function($, window, document, undefined){
   var expMod = (function(){
   /* ****************
    * private members
    * ****************/
   var defaults = {
      prop: 'Hello!',
      say: function(){
         alert(this.prop);
      }
   };
   /* ***************
    * public members
    * ***************/
   return {
      pluginName: 'expModule',
      init: function(elem, options) {
         this.element = elem;
         this.$element = $(elem);
         this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      },
      say: function() {
         defaults.say();
      }
   };
})();

if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
   Object.create = function(obj) {
      "use strict";
      function F() {}
      F.prototype = obj;
      return new F();
   };
};

//extend jquery
$.fn.expMod = function(options) {
   return this.each(function() {
      var mod = Object.create(expMod);
      mod.init(this, options);
      //$.data(this, 'expModule', mod);
      $(this).data('expModule', mod);
   });
};

}(jQuery, window, document));

$('h1').on('click', function(evt){
   var temp = {prop: 'Hej (Danish)!'};
   $( "#first" ).expMod(this, temp);
   $( "#second" ).expMod(this);
   ////////////////////////
   //get the first plugin//
   ////////////////////////
   var first = $( "#first" ).data('expModule');
   var text = '';
   //iterate over it's properties & print
   for(option in first)
      //if(first.hasOwnProperty(option))
         text += option+'='+first[option]+', ';
   //say!
   $( "#first" ).addClass('dot').text(text).data('expModule').say();
   /////////////////////////
   //get the second plugin//
   /////////////////////////
   second = $( "#second" ).data('expModule');
   text = '';
   //iterate over it's properties & print
   for(option in second)
      if(second.hasOwnProperty(option))
         text += option+'='+second[option]+', ';
   //say!
   $( "#second" ).addClass('dot').text(text).data('expModule').say();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Questions**
1) when I click on `h1` text I can see 2 messages of 'Hello!' but I passed object `{prop: 'Hej (Danish)!'}` during construction of my first module, what's the problem though?

2) for another one time `this` turns to a huge dissapointment: when we iterate over the module properties function `hasOwnProperty()` is unable to recognize **everything** in literal notation form, except the ones that we set up with `this`! Can we force javascript to play nicely here?

3) One developer out there wanted to keep track of animation variables so he just filled with ~1000 lines the `Private Members` part of the plugin: many functions getting and setting a bunch of private variables ***that they rely upon***; ok up to now but, do we have an alternative to this approach? I mean what if we have 2 sliders, is it guaranteed that everyone sees it's own space of private variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

- firstly, while I was creating my plugins at the onclick event handler I passed `this` as argument, I shouldn't and
- secondly, my `say()` function is defined and called the wrong way from my plugin; we shouldn't use `this` on a private object while what we were meant was `this` of the constructed object that is returned from the self-invoking function. Actually, it's a good idea to completely erase `this` from our private section when using this pattern and keep it only inside the return object-the public one! So, `defaults.say(arg)` accepts an argument and the public `say()` is defined as: `say: function() { defaults.say(this.options.prop); }`